# Ceiling for search with Google

Tags: google, google-search-console

I use Google Webmaster tools to follow my website and I'm confused about search stats. For several months, the curve about search requests reached the limit on 3000 search by day. The curve never goes over 3000 search by day.

Does Google limits request per day for a small website?
Can Webmaster Tools not show more than 3000 requests per day?

Answer (score 1):

The searches are not being limited.  The graph in Webmaster Tools can show more than 3000 search queries per day -- the graph vertical axis adapts to the actual number of queries measured.  The maximum shown on the axis is chosen so that you can see the details of the graph better.  If your site is generating more than 2000 searches per day sometimes, but rarely or never more than 3000, then the Tools graph will probably choose 3000 as the maximum value on the vertical axis.